# Shared C# components to be used in another application from 2 different GIT Repositories

Tags: c#, git, nuget

Basically I have a general application (used across multiple systems) & then I have individual dlls which are kept in different solutions to the main application. In some cases the individual dlls will contain references to some components from the main application.

I want to store the main application's solution in a separate Git repository to the other solutions.

How can I have 2 repositories while one of the repositories use components from the other?

Comment: Asking "What's the best approach to X" is a pretty safe way to be closed as opinion-based. You may want to edit your question, so it explains what _problem_ you have and what _question_ you want to ask, so an answer to it would solve your problem. In your case that would probably start with "How can I ... "

Answer (score 0):

A NuGet library would be the way to go. However it can be a lot of work to set it up propperly.

A more dirty way is to create a CMD script which will clone the repo, copy the files and include it in your project.
It can look something like this.

```
echo Make sure to close your IDE or any other programs that have any file in the source or bin folder open.

:: delete source files
del source /q
del bin /q

mkdir source
cd source

:: clone new source files
git clone https://github.com/your_repo

:: go back to root
cd ../

:: build source files
dotnet build source\path_to.csproj --configuration production --output bin/ProjectName

pause
```

Then include the dll as a solution item and include it as a dll reference to your project

```
<Reference Include="your_project_name">
  <HintPath>..\path_to_dll_you_just_build.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

Comment: You are probably better off cloning, and then fetching in the future. But this works too.